# iTunes U resume download

Tags: itunes, download

Lecture videos on iTunes U can be quite large (~300 MB). Can I get iTunes U to resume a download after any interruption?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can - click on "Copy iTunes U URL", then use something like wget to get that url
Open the resultant file, and you will find a whole lot of URLs in it, with the relevant episodes. (in my case ending in .mp4)
Then use "wget -c" to get the episodes by each url, and it support resume perfectly.... (unless the server doesn't)

Using this method, I have been successfully resuming Stanford iPhone Dev Lectures, which iTunes kept on doing from the beginning...

iTunes.... when it works, it's great... when it doesn't...  hmmmmmm

Comment: you can also use any download tool, like JDownloader for example that let you manage and resume downloads easily

Answer (score 0):

Itunes U is just a catalogue/listing service, it downloads from many different sources.

Typically you can pause/resume in Itunes but it also will depend if the server you are downloading from supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna show you something really easy than wget. You don't even need it, or anything else at all.

Here is how we do it:

1. On a webpage, say for e.g., the Stanford University online class Fall 2011 for iPhone app development, here you will be shown list of videos that are available and you can click on and it will open in iTunes.
2. When it opens in iTunes, click on `get it all`, and start downloading all, but don't download it just pause them all by using pause all button.
3. Now go to iTunes,under the library in the corner, e.g., it will show under collections "iPhone and iPad application...." click it, it will show you the list of files with get option.
4. Just right-click on any of the file, and select copy iTunes URL.
5. Paste it in your browser and go.
6. You will get list of files and you can just download it outside iTunes, using any download manager, or in your browser.

For example, I'll just right-click on `encloser.mp4` file and select copy link location (Firefox). Then paste it in orbit or any other download manager.

I can pause it and resume it. Simple. I can also paste the link in Firefox itself and download it there without any download manager.

Don't use any wget or any other thing.